# Make highlight brush the same as control brush without specifying colour

Tags: wpf, resources, background, listviewitem

I want to ensure that a selected ListViewItem's non-focused background is the same as the focused background.  I know that the common way of doing this is as follows:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
```

However, the problem is that I don't want to specify a colour, I merely want the Brush returned by the static resource whose key is ControlBrushKey to be the same as the one for HighlightBrushKey.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
           Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I know it works to set two properties to match, not sure if it will work in your context, but it's worth a shot:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Blue"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                 Color="{DynamicResourse SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey.Color}"/>
```

I tested this using a TextBox as a playground. I'm not sure of your exact application, but here was my test markup:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
    <TextBox.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                Color="{DynamicResource SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey.Color}" />
    </TextBox.Foreground>
</TextBox>
```

This just set the background to blue, and the foreground to the background, which was the expected result.

Comment: It doesn't work. Try the following and you'll see what I mean. Select an item from the ListView, then click on the TextBox. <Grid> <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition /> <RowDefinition /> </Grid.RowDefinitions> <ListView> <ListView.ItemContainerStyle> <Style TargetType="ListViewItem"> <Style.Resources> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource SystemColors.HighlightBru